depthimage_to_laserscan_ros2 didn't work with camera in humble
I'm trying to make cloudpoint transform with depthimage_to_laserscan in ROS2 humble,my board is jetson orin.
I get the depthimage_to_laserscan package by git clone.And modify the topic remapping in file depthimage_to_laserscan-launch.py because my camera depth topic named /camera/depth/image_raw,so it became remappings=[('depth','/camera/depth/image_raw')],then I launch this launch file,and the same time I launch my camera,node depthimage_to_laserscan will die.



Can anybody help?I'm soooo confused

Welcome to Robotics maxine, but I'm afraid that it is not clear how to help you. We prefer practical, answerable questions, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the Robotics question checklist to edit your question to make it clearer.

If I launch depthimage_to_laserscan-launch.py and launch my camera at the same time,the node will soon die without any hints.No any other phenomenon.

Please explain how you have setup your system, what and how you have installed on your system, how you are setting up your environment, and the exact commands you're using to run as well as the exact console outputs. What you're looking to do is provide the ability of people here to reproduce your problem. Without that we can only guess what might be your problem.

I edit again,what else should I offer?

Please copy and paste the text and don't screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable. And we also need how you have installed the executables on your system and how you've setup your environment. Also what's in the log file referenced in the console output? And what's in the config file that you're passing?

git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan -b ros2로 build하면 잘 되여
저두 humble에서 잘 안되서 일단 ros2 foxy 설치하고 나서 foxy-devel checkout해서 해 봤는데 ros2 foxy에서는 잘 되더라구여 그래서 다시 humble에서 해봤는데 잘 됐어여
